# Density of restrictions of $p$-harmonic functions on a hypersurface

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, approximation-theory, p-laplace

Let $\omega,\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq2$, be bounded smooth domains so that $\bar\omega\subset\Omega$.
Let $1<p<\infty$.
Define the boundary space $B=W^{1,p}(\omega)/W^{1,p}_0(\omega)$; this is the space of possible boundary values of a function in $W^{1,p}(\omega)$ in the Sobolev sense.

We can restrict any $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ to $\partial\omega$ and get a function in $B$.
(More formally, we can first restrict the function to $\omega$ and then quotient by $W^{1,p}_0(\omega)$.)

> **Is the set
>   $
> A=\{u|_{\partial\omega};u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega),u\text{ is }p\text{-harmonic}\}
> $
>   dense in $B$?**

I am mainly interested in the nonlinear case $p\neq2$, but references or ideas for the case $p=2$ are also appreciated.
I convinced myself that $A$ is dense in $B$ if $p=2$ and the domains are cocentric balls, but this is far from what I want.

A function $u$ is [$p$-harmonic](http://www.math.wustl.edu/ac/AlFestWorkshop.pdf) if it solves $\Delta_pu:=\operatorname{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=0$ in the weak sense.